# CSS background style with gradient color

Tags: background, background-color, css

Somebody know how I can make a gradient color to background with css properties?
If not posible do this with css, any idea to do it with other way other than placing an image?

Thanks in advance!

See follow image:[image]

Comment: Note that because of the vertical symmetry, if you were to use an image, you would only need to use one that is 1-pixel high, and then define the CSS so that it is repeated (search for repeat-y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good tools out there that help you get the most compatible code:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: They also have an awesome Chrome extension :)